# Factoy pattern in python - Separate class or function wrapped?

Tags: python, factory-pattern

I think to have a use case for the factory pattern method in python and have two ideas how to implement it (see below). Both work, but are they really the same? Option2 looks much clearer to me, despite having a few more lines. Is my gut feeling right? Or is there a third better option?

#### Option 1

```
def inner_factory_func(a):
    class Inner:
        def __init__(self, b):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b

        def call(self):
            return self.a + self.b

    return Inner

inner_factory = inner_factory_func('a')
inner = inner_factory('b')
res = inner.call()  # ='ab'
```

#### Option 2

```
class Inner:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def call(self):
        return self.a+self.b

class InnerFactory:
    def __init__(self,a ):
        self.a = a
    def create(self,b) -> Inner2:
        return Inner(self.a,b)

inner_factory = InnerFactory('a')
inner = inner_factory.create('b')
res = inner.call() # ='ab'
```

Comment: Why are you defining your class inside your factory?  these two are not doing the same thing. The first is a *class factory* which is likely not what you want

Comment: The first version creates a new (unique) class every time, the latter does not, by why not just use a function?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : You mean the first option is a *class*-factory in contrast to a *object* factory ? If yes, thanks, didn't realize it beforehand.

Comment: @gebbissimo yes, precisely. It returns `Inner`, which refers to the class you define inside the fucntion. It creates a new class on each invocation.

Comment: @thebjorn: Concerning why not use a function: The actual use case is more complex than the one above.